# iTextSharp Date-Time to just Date in PdfPCell

Tags: c#, datetime, itext

I've got a button that converts a modal window to a pdf, inside that pdf I've got a cell which lists dates for the payments. I want only the date to be displayed and not the time as it always shows 00:00:00.

Here's what I'm using to get the Date from the Database.

```
PdfPCell cellT1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dtTable.Rows[i]["PAYDATE"].ToString(), f));
cellT1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cellT1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cellT1);
```

How can I convert this to just Date instead of Date-Time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string dateTime = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dtTable.Rows[i]["PAYDATE"]);

PdfPCell cellT1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dateTime, f));
cellT1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cellT1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cellT1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used to get the Date from the Database.

```
PdfPCell cellT1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dtTable.Rows[i]["PAYDATE"].FormattedValue.ToString(), f));
cellT1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cellT1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cellT1);
```